# JPA: After merge() contains evaulate still to false

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

My major problem is to remove (+persist) an entity:

I have an entity `Property` which has several `PropertyAttributes` - managed as list, i.e.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "property", cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinFetch(value = JoinFetchType.INNER)
private List<PropertyAttribute> propertyAttribute;
```

in the `PropertyAttribute` I have as well a reference to the `Property`, i.e.

```
@Id
@JsonIgnore
@JoinColumn(name = "property_id")
@ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
private Property property;
```

the main problem arise when when I want to remove some of the attributes, e.g.

```
getEntityManager().remove(attrEntity);
```

because this is not found in the entity. If I introduce some code like

```
if (!getEntityManager().contains(attrEntity)) {
    attrEntity = getEntityManager().merge(attrEntity);
}
System.out.println(getEntityManager().contains(attrEntity)); //==> always false
```

I have no clue why the `merge()` has no effect on the overall. Any ideas what to check or what to change?

Plus: I tried the workaround to remove the `PropertyAttribute` from the `Property` itself and `merge(myChangedProperty)` it but the removed attribute is not persisted, i.e. still in the database

Comment: try `flush()` after merge

Comment: `flush()` fails with the `Exception` that no transaction is active - which is quite strange even if I embrace the merge with a `getTransaction().begin()` ... Additional ideas?

Comment: more orthodox seems MasterEntity.propertyAttribute.remove(attrEntity) (depends on code part we dont know)

Comment: BTW most java programmers like List (which is psychologically natural), in JPA context are many advantages with Set

Comment: getEntityManager isn't returning you the same EntityManager instance. It is returning your container's proxy, which is obtaining a new one underneath the covers on these calls.  Try wrapping your method in a transaction, as this forces the container to keep and reuse the EntityManager.

Comment: @Chris: yeah - this is the proper hint - I did it like this and than the problem is fixed - THX for the hint!!!